# Custom Report Type Broken

Tags: permissions, change-set, reporting

I deployed a change set that included two custom report types for accounts with opportunities.  These two custom report types sat next to an existing custom report type.

Ever since this deployment took place, the existing custom report type has failed to display any results.  It's as if the original custom report type relationship has been broken (accounts with at least one opportunity).

Has anyone experienced this problem before and if so, how did they resolve it?

Comment: The Report Types are 'Deployed' rather than 'In Development' ?

Comment: What else, if anything, was in the Change Set?

Comment: @techtrekker - great comment and I've upvoted... but I suspect user218 is a SysAdmin so he should see results anyway.

Comment: Cheers @eyescream!

Comment: 1. Can you be more specific on "failed to display any results"? Is it just 0 rows or some error that prevents it from running?
2. Can you build a new report (from scratch) based on this broken rep. type and see what happens?

Comment: I just experienced this problem myself and am working with Salesforce Support. We deployed a Change Set adding fields and the updated CRT. Our existing reports lost all filters and new reports based on the CRT return 0 rows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm always falling for this one so maybe it's a valid answer.

I'm a System Administrator so I see all data but in terms of Role hierarchy I'm not on the top of the food chain; there's "Director of IT", "CEO" etc. above me. When I make a new Opportunity-related report it memorizes the hierarchy and gives me 0 rows in the edit page even with "all opportunities" selected. I need to run the report, click the top Role, then I'll truly see all data in the org I want and can happily go back to crafting and saving the report.

Org wide defaults for Opportunities are "private + grant access using hierarchies", same for Accounts.

I suspect it's something like that because if the report type is truly "broken" you get a more specific message.

**EDIT**

Check if any of following has changed:

- admin has disabled "Allow Reports" on custom object (if there's any in the report type),
- filter in report is based on a field that was deleted / user lost the visibility due to field-level security
- master-detail changes (again, that would be only on custom object if there's any in the report type, not on Account-Opportunity link)

Comment: Yes, I'm an SysAdmin.  I can verify that this is not a role hierarchy problem because I've tested the problem using an admin account at the org level.

Comment: No custom objects are used in the report.  No security changes were applied (as far as I can see).  No master-details changes.

Comment: Chnages made in the change set were on custom fields (being added), custom report types, and page layouts.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue? I am experiencing the same issue with "Obsolete Report" error. I know it has something to do with namespace

Comment: Basically the report type, report, and dashboard are not updatable so everytime you change the schema of object you need to create new report,report type, or dashboard when deploying to packaged environment