# Change Set deployed Custom Report Type Incorrectly

Tags: reporting, change-set, custom-report-type

In my org and sandbox I have a Custom Report Type (CRT), `Accounts with Applications`, based on `Accounts with at least one Opportunity`. I recently used a Change Set to deploy new custom fields on the Opportunity as well as updating the fields available on the CRT. The Change Set validated and deployed but not without odd behavior:

1. Existing reports based on the CRT lost all filters, including date ranges. When reconfigured they produce results, but if you try to modify the columns present then you get no records returned.
2. New reports based on the CRT show no records (tested as System Admin, top of the role hierarchy.)
3. The CRT's field layout is correct; the sections and fields are present as expected
4. The CRT's object relationship is wrong. It is Accounts with at least one other Custom Object

I've verified the XML in the Change Set on both sides is correct and identical. I've tried deploying a brand new Change Set with just the CRT and nothing changes.

Has anybody experienced this?

Similar: [Custom Report Type Broken](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/custom-report-type-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be Administrator error. A lookup on the Opportunity had its `Related List Label` set to *Opportunities* so when building a Custom Report Type *Opportunities* appeared twice in the drop-down list. The wrong entry was selected in the sandbox and was then propagated to production (where the `Related List Label` was correct.)

Now that the `Related List Label` has been corrected I can work on getting the Custom Report Type and Reports restored.